# Java While Loop checks the time but not performing a method

Tags: java, swing, loops, while-loop, messagebox

In this code a while loop is supposed to check the time, and if the time is equal to 7 PM, then display a message box.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    Enable.setEnabled(false);
    Date d = new Date();
    int hrs = d.getHours();
    int mins = d.getMinutes();

        while((1 + 1) == 2) { 
            if(hrs == 19 && mins == 21) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                    "It's 7:21 PM!",
                    "Alerts",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Pushing a button will do that code. If you push the button before it is 7 PM, the GUI will freeze (I don't care about that), and when it turns to 7 PM, it won't display the message box. If you click the button when it *is* 7 PM, then it will display the message box...

Comment: where did you put values into the variables "hrs" and "mins"? They will keep whatever value they have when the program enters the while loop and never get updated.

Comment: also is press button , you push a door, if hrs is never 19 then it's not gonna change until you run in another thread

Comment: when are you expecting 1+1 to not equal 2? (I'm aware that you're trying to loop until break.  That is an awful way to do it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `hrs` and `mins` in your loop otherwise the initialization of them, I assume at the time of pushing the button will always hold the time when the button was pushed.

This is why it works when pushed at 7pm but otherwise will not.

So do something like this

```
while(true) //Equivalent to what you had 
{ 
      if(hrs == 19 && mins == 00) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
               "It's 7:00 PM!",
               "Time Alert",
               JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
           System.exit(0);
           break;
       }
       //Refresh your hrs and mins here
       Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // Probably dont really want to actually get an instance every time
       hrs = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       mins = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing while((1 + 1) == 2) to get an infinite loop, you can just do: while(true) or for(;;)
And this question is unanswerable without any further information or code about your hrs and mins variables

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you're using 1+1=2 to have a continuous loop. you could use `while(true){...}` instead.
Also, the while loop wouldn't be practical for this case. There is an example on this page that does something similar (Alarm Clock): http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule/index.html

this was their example. I updated it to suite your task.

```
public class AlarmClock {

    private final Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    private final int hourOfDay, minute, second;

    public AlarmClock() {
        this.hourOfDay = 19;
        this.minute = 0;
        this.second = 0;
    }

    public void start() {
        scheduler.schedule(new SchedulerTask() {
            public void run() {
                soundAlarm();
            }
            private void soundAlarm() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                            "It's 7:00 PM!",
                            "Time Alert",
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        System.exit(0);
                // Start a new thread to sound an alarm...
            }
        }, new DailyIterator(hourOfDay, minute, second));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AlarmClock alarmClock = new AlarmClock();
        alarmClock.start();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.